# How do i compare variables and then assign a new value if the condition is true?

Tags: python, python-3.6

```
rounds = int(input())

for x in range(rounds):
    score1, score2 = input().split()
    score1 = int(score1)
    score2 = int(score2)
    if score1 > score2:
        sub = score1 - score2
    else:
        sub = score2 - score1
```

What i need to do is to have a variable (say, lead) whose value would be equal to the `sub` (`lead = sub`). Then I need to compare `lead` to the new value of the `sub`(because of the iteration of the for loop) and if the new value is greater than the value of `lead`. Then i need to replace `lead` by that new value of sub that we got.

Finally, i would then get the final lead which would be greatest of all.

Comment: Sorry, wrote the spelling of then as thenn

Comment: Use [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55286079/edit) to make changes even after posting.

Comment: Thank you for the info! I was new to this at that time haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize `lead` with 0, and use the `max` function to pick the greater of `lead` and the new score difference, which you can calculate with the `abs` function:

```
lead = 0
for x in range(rounds):
    score1, score2 = input().split()
    score1 = int(score1)
    score2 = int(score2)
    lead = max(lead, abs(score1 - score2))
```

Comment: `lead = 0` would be sufficient (and consistent with `sub` being an `int`), since `abs(...)` can't be less than 0.

Comment: Indeed. Updated as suggested. Thanks.